# Symfony2 default number format

Tags: php, symfony

I want to change the default number format in a Symfony 2 project.

Instead of printing the numbers like `10.55` I want to display the decimal separator as a comma `10,55`.

Not in the a Twig template but in all the forms. If I want to that is a Twig is as easy as use the [number_format function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html).

I've already set my locale in the config.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using a `number` type field in your form type.

So you could use the [`grouping`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#grouping) option:

> [...] numbers will be grouped with a comma or period (depending on your
>   locale): 12345.123 would display as 12,345.123.

Your code will look as following:

```
// src/Acme/MyBundle/Form/Type/MyType.php
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('mynumber', 'number', array('grouping' => true));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my';
    }
}
```

(you have the same option when using the [`money`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html) field type)

Comment: no. As you can see in your own answer, the grouping option adds a comma for grouping the numbers higher than 1000. What I need is to replace the character that divides a the decimal part. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Well, you are right :) What locale are you using? Symfony uses [`NumberFormatter` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) and it is stated that: `For example, the number 12345.67 is "12,345.67" in the US, "12 345,67" in France and "12.345,67" in Germany. `

Comment: in config.yml, default_locale, i'm using "es". What you said in your last comment is exactly what I need. How can i, for exemple, adopt the French format (I do need the french format ;))

Comment: I just tried on a `money` type field using the french locale (`fr`) and it displays as `12345,67` (without the space between `12` and `345` but the `,` is here). Your goal is to keep the local to `es` but use the NumberFormatter as if it was `fr`?

Comment: mhm... i guess yes, this is it

Comment: From what I understand from the [transformer (line 159)](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer.php) they are using for `number`, I don't think what you want to achieve is doable in a simple way. I think the best way would be to write your own data transformer but I don't know if this is the way you want to go. I can update my answer with an example if you need.

Answer (score -1):

I also used the 'number' field type but one doesn't need the grouping option in the form type, from what I could test. It is enough to render it in the twig template: see example below where `{{ discount.discountRate }}` is a float. If you replace it with '75.3869', you will find '75,39'

```
{# number with 2 decimal places, decimal comma, no thousands separator #}
{{ discount.discountRate|number_format(2, ',', '') }}%
```